# StartException in service persistenceunit - possible issue Hibernate queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, liferay

I have a Liferay portlet project that I'd like to deploy on JBoss + Liferay. This worked fine earlier but other project that this depends on changed over time. When I try to deploy my portlet, I get the following exception

```
09:07:40,261 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
09:07:40,608 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
09:07:43,046 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."biz.modit.tit.gop.education.clientportlets.adaptivetest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#GOPPersistence": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."biz.modit.tit.gop.education.clientportlets.adaptivetest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#GOPPersistence": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.loader.BasicLoader.isBag(BasicLoader.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.loader.BasicLoader.postInstantiate(BasicLoader.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.<init>(QueryLoader.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:974)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
```

Based on this I suspect that there's a problem with one of the queries in the entity project (containing all the jpa entities and named queries, etc). So is there a tool for checking the correctness of the hql queries? Or do you have any other suspicion regarding what could cause the problem?
The above exception is the only exception I get regarding the issue.

Comment: Which version of hiberate do you use?

Comment: The highest level pom contains <hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version> and it defines hibernate dependencies using this variable, although in the entity's pom the hibernate dependencies are redefined without a specified version number, so I guess it uses the latest available version.

Comment: @Peter can you do code check near by line number 1767 in ServiceControllerImpl.java? Or post near by code here.

Comment: ServiceControllerImpl.java from 1759 to 1784: http://pastebin.com/UtBnH6tp What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: can u edit that and comment where line 1767 is coming. i am lazy to do calculation :P :) coz my lazy property set to false

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dP6NsPgh I've put a comment there

Comment: Sorry its not traceable with that code looks fine there. This error comes at the point where you are using Named Queries.

Comment: Or is your app multithreaded?

Comment: No, and I think you're right about the named queries it's just there are quite a lot of them to check by hand :/